# Can i send multiple values in one input as an array?

Tags: php, html

For my interface I would like my radio input to send an array to my php calculator.

With 1 input it works like this:

HTML: `<input type="radio" name="brand[]" value="60">`

PHP: `$storagebrand = ($_POST)['brand'];`

output: `Array ( [0] => 60)`

I would like to be able to send an array trough that single radio button like this:

HTML: `<input type="radio" name="brand[]" value="60, 20, 30">`

PHP: `$storagebrand = ($_POST)['brand'];`

output: `Array ( [0] => 60, [1] => 20, [2] => 30)`

Obviously this doesn't work since it gives me:

output: `Array ( [0] => "60, 20, 30" )`

How could i make it as requested?

Comment: You can also overwrite the form send event in js.

Comment: @phpquestion This seems like an odd use of the radio button. The purpose of that element is to select a single value from multiple options.

Comment: You can put the values in a separate field that gets populated with the required values when the radio button gets selected

Comment: @PatrickQ Can you suggest an alternative? The case here seems to be that the user need to choose from several groups of numbers and that each group has internal dependencies (i.e. you can't mix and match). Using radio buttons to differentiate between each group seems like a reasonable solution. An alternative would be to have each radio button reference a group id which is resolved on the backend, but we don't know if the group values vary based on other input.

Comment: @FabianGillenius If OP has extenuating circumstances that justify atypical uses, it is up to them to make that explicit in the question.  It is not up to us to use conjecture as to what the situation may or may not be.

Comment: @NikhilSahu The question is tagged with php and html. Since your comment implies using Javascript, you might want to expand on your suggestion a little to make it more clear. Seeing as this is somewhat of a beginner's question, it might be safe to assume that  OP is not familiar with Javascript.

Comment: right you are @FabianGillenius. I was implying JS. My bad.
@phpquestion What you are getting is a string value in `Array ( [0] => 60, 20, 30 )`. You can split the value by comma and get the required array.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php
Radio button is not multi-valued. you will need another element to get this directly

Comment: @PatrickQ I agree, the question is lacking. However, OP has stated that the normal application of radio buttons does not fit their needs and that they need to be able to select a group of numbers. How would you go about doing that, using only PHP and HTML?

Comment: @FabianGillenius Saying that you _want_ to do something is not the same as giving solid justification for doing so.  I'm not going any further into this.  My point was simply that what they're requesting is an _odd_ use.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the quick responses. I managed to solve it by using the following:

```
$storageall = ($_POST)["brand"];
$storagebrand = (explode(" ",$storageall));
rsort($storagebrand);
```